# Textfield bug after upgrading to IOS 17.0

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, ios17

I have a textfield to allow users to input their numbers. It works well until I upgrade to IOS 17.0 yesterday.
After upgrading to IOS 17.0, the number input by user can't be cleared when user wants to input another number. More specifically, the last figure can't be deleted.For example, the user originally input 50, and he/she wants to delete it to input another figure. But 5 can't be deleted and only 0 is deleted. So user can't input a new number in the textfield. Is a bug from IOS17.0? How can I fix it. My code about the textfield is as following:

```
 TextField("Focus Time", value: $userViewModel.focusTime, format: .number)
                                    .frame(width: 220, height: nil)
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                                    .font(Font.system(size: 25, design: .default))
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
                                    .focused($textIsFocused1)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        textIsFocused1.toggle()
                                    }
```

Comment: have you tried without the `.onTapGesture{...}`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I can easily delete the "5" inn "50". Can you describe in detail the steps you took?

Comment: No, I can't. delete it. .onTapGesture{...} is used for letting keyboard disappear. Otherwise, user can't see the below buttons because the space limitation.

Comment: Hi, Sweeper, Are you using IOS17? It works well before upgrading to IOS17. But the bug shows after upgrading IOS17.

Comment: I found an answer which seems to be related to the issue:Current iOS 17 bug: text fields in scroll views don’t work, but they work in lists and forms.

Edit: meant to say focus state doesn’t work. But it's published three months ago. I don't know whether there is any solution for it now.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several times, I found the bug is related with EnvironmentObject var. If I change userViewModel.focusTime(which is an EnvironmentObject var) to focusTime(which is a State var), the view works well. There is no any issue. import SwiftUI

struct CustomPomodoroTimerView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userViewModel: CurrentUserViewModel

```
@FetchRequest var theUser: FetchedResults<User>

init(filterForTheUser: String) {
    _theUser = FetchRequest<User>(sortDescriptors: [],predicate: (NSPredicate(format: "userID == %@", filterForTheUser)))}

@State var user: User?

@State var focusTime = 25

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

@FocusState private var textIsFocused1: Bool

var body: some View {
    
    ZStack(){
        Image("MyPomodoro")
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack(alignment:.center){
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                Text("My Pomodoro Timer")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .font(.system(size:40,weight:.bold))
                    .padding(.top,50)
                
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                
                VStack(alignment:.leading){
                    
                    VStack(alignment:.leading) {
                        
                        HStack(){
                            Image("Timer")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 80,height:80)
                            
                            Text("Focus Time")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.system(size:35,weight:.bold))
                        }
                        
                        HStack() {
                            TextField("Focus Time", value: $focusTime, format: .number)
                                .frame(width: 220, height: nil)
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 25, design: .default))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
                                .focused($textIsFocused1)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    textIsFocused1.toggle()
                                }
                            
                            Text("min")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.system(size:35,weight:.bold))
                            
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 50)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you provide code? I am having similar issues and would like to see what you did. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Eric, I add my codes in my answer. I only change "@EnvironmentObject var" to "@State var", and then it can work well. I don't know why. But it works.